# 'UIKeyboardDidShowNotification' is unavailable: not available on tvOS error in react-native-safe-area-context after React Native update

Tags: xcode, react-native, tvos, apple-tv, react-native-safe-area-view

I recently updated my React Native version from 0.69.8-2 to 0.71.11 and started encountering an error that I haven't been able to resolve. The error message is:

`'UIKeyboardDidShowNotification' is unavailable: not available on tvOS`

This error is coming from the `react-native-safe-area-context` package and it's preventing me from building my project in Xcode.

Here's the exact error message:

```
/Repo/node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context/ios/RNCSafeAreaProvider.m:18:53 'UIKeyboardDidShowNotification' is unavailable: not available on tvOS
```

I've tried searching for solutions online but haven't found any discussions specifically related to this error. I'm hoping someone here might have encountered this issue before and can provide some guidance.

Here are some details about my environment:

- React Native version: 0.71.11
- react-native-safe-area-context version: (4.6.4)
- Xcode version: (Version 14.3.1 (14E300c))
- Targeted platform: tvOS

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

I want to build my Application on Xcode

Comment: Looks like they released a fix earlier today: https://github.com/th3rdwave/react-native-safe-area-context/issues/411

Comment: @Abe
yes they fixed it. i have raised this issue there also.